# Substitute grid's background when changing VisualState in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-store-apps

My Windows Store app has a few VisualStates, and for each of them I would like to have a different picture in the background (which is related to orientaton of the device, size of the screen etc.) From what I've found in the Internet, one option would be to use a storyboard, but I can only find examples related to changing colour of the background (which is not suitable for me, as I have an Image in the background and not plain colour brush.)

I thought about something like this:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBrush" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" />
</Storyboard>
```

But there is no substitute for `ColorAnimation` to use with Image. Is there any known XAML/C# solution, or a standard way to do this background image source substitution for different Visual States (maybe using Visual Studio or Blend?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use different backgrounds for different visual states one needs to have multiple images spread in the background, with only one of them visible for each visual state (and rest of the images collapsed.) It may be important to change zindexes of elements to set them "on top" of the images in the background.